# Amazon MWS Get Product Price .NET Library C#

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-mws

I was wondering if anyone had a working example of the Amazon MWS .NET Library. The one Amazon only point to local XML files and doesn't really provide too much detail in their documentation. The following is what I am trying to retrieve from the MWS service.

Lowest used price, lowest new price, sales rank, any sales ranks of other categories, title, image url, amazon buyback price, amount of third party sellers, weight of item.

Any help would be nice at this point. I have been working on this for two days and haven't gotten any where.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it all out and if you need to know how it works I have posted some code on github. https://github.com/nyneaxis/Amazon_MWS you will need your own Amazon keys.

Comment: `+1` hello, can i ask something? what are `merchantId`, `marketplaceId`, `applicationName`, and `applicationVersion`?

Comment: if you can have some time, can we chat here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25057/amazon-mws-get-product-price?

Comment: Where did you get all of those class files for Amazon? The MWS library I have (its called CBAMWSLibrary) only supports a handful of functions, namely building Envelopes/Feeds and submitting them.  And the only envelope message types available are for updating orders.